# How to invoke button click without explicit click on that button

Tags: java, events, actionlistener, sphinx4

I am developing an application in JAVA that takes input as speech and performs actions. What I want to achieve is button click without explicitly clicking on that button.

The idea is to take the speech input, use the result which is a String object, and invoke button click just by speech result.

I have been able to use that result to start notepad or browser.

For speech processing I am using Sphinx4 and eclipse IDE.

Example:

```
Result result = recognizer.recognize();

        if (result != null) 
        {
            String resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();

              if((resultText.equalsIgnoreCase("Notepad"))
               { 
                try
                {

                 pr[0] = new ProcessBuilder("notepad.exe").start();

                   }
```

Here resultText is the String object containing the user's input. Here I tried opening notepad if speaker says notepad.

But how to use this resultText to invoke actionPerformed of a button....?

Example: How to invoke this method of a JFrame without button click

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{   
    NewJFrame1 frame = new NewJFrame1();

    frame.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
 }
```

Comment: Call `jButton1ActionPerformed` like any other method? Since that method doesn't appear to use `evt`, pass `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If pressing the button does more than just invoking the `jButton1ActionPerformed` method you showed here, use the [`doClick()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick()) method on the JButton object, which I'm guessing you called `jButton1`:

```
jButton1.doClick();
```

---

You can also cut out the middleman and just call your method directly, like any other. (This will only work if your handler method doesn't use the event argument object `evt`. Since you've declared it `private`, the calling method must also be in the same class.)

```
jButton1ActionPerformed(null);
```